# Running a socket stream in a thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I have an application that opens a connection with 2 sockets (in and out) and I want to have them working in a thread.

The reason that I want them to be in a separate thread is that I don't want my application to freeze when I receive data, and this can happen anytime as long as the application is running.

Currently I have a class that handle also network communication and I run this class in an NSOperation, I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

I'm not very familiar with threading so guys if you could give me some help I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that you can use the same socket to send and receive data — they're generally bi-directional. You should be able to share a reference to the same socket among multiple threads of execution.

Second, unless you'll be receiving large amounts of data and have experienced performance issues with your UI, I would delay optimizing for it. (Don't get me wrong, this is a good consideration, but premature optimization is the root of all evil, and simpler is generally better if it performs adequately.)

Third, [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/) objects are "single-shot", meaning that once the `main` method completes, the operation task cannot be used again. This may or may not be conducive to your networking model. You might also look at [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/). The fact that you already have the functionality "factored out" bodes well for your design, whatever turns out to be best.

Lastly, threading is a complex topic, but a good place to start (especially for Objective-C) is Apple's [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/).